# AWS Mysql to external server data transfer very slow

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to set up a data transfer between my two servers.I notice the transfer of data between both these server is very slow. I use **python 3.6** as my scripting language to connect and transfer data between both the server.

I have a sever hosted  with a **private provider** (1&1). This server currently host my application and database. I would say this to be Server A.

I created another server in AWS recently. Lets say this to be server B. I created a small database in this and i am trying to transfer data to my existing private server (Server A). I tried the below two approach

**Approach 1:** I have **EC2 Instance (t2micro)**. I have MySQL DB installed in this. I am trying to send around 2000 records to my private server (Server A). It took more than 2 minutes to send this data.

**Approach 2:** I have an **Aurora server less** (MySQL comparable) and a lambda function (in python 3.6) which invokes the Aurora DB and transmits data to my existing server at private provider (Server A). I am sending around 2000 records (same as above case). This function takes more than 2 minutes to complete the data transfer. My DB is hosted in private subnet and i have a NAT instance in public subnet.

For testing purpose, when i initiate the python script from private server (Server A) to connect to AWS and load the data to my private server, it **takes hardly 15 seconds** to transfer the same 2000 records.

When i initiate the python script from AWS to connect to my private server and load data to my private server (using two approach i mentioned above), it **takes more than 2 minutes** to transfer the same 2000 records.

Can anyone let me know why does it take so much time to move data from AWS to external server. What should i do improve the performance in AWS side. I am looking to move my data processing part to AWS for now.

Thanks,
SP

Comment: Performance is directly related to instance size. T2.micro is very small for a database. Pick a larger instance and re-benchmark.

Comment: I tried to change the instance type and try.. but not much help, same results. ALso in that case approach 2 should have worked fine, as it was using Aurora serverless , Lambda and NAT instance, in this case it should scale up automatically. but approach 2 also gave almost the same results (more than 2 mins to load 2000 records).  I am not sure if there is anything additional to setup in AWS side.

Comment: Please be specific. What instance size did you pick? Going from t2.micro to t2.small won't make much of a difference. Going from t2.micro to m5.large will make a big difference. You mentioned NAT instance. What size? For auto scaling you need to have sustained requirements, not two minutes worth. You have so many "vague" components that it is difficult to help you.

Comment: i changed from t2micro to m5large, and tried to execute... it took the same 2 minutes.  I am using NAT Gateway and not NAT instance in my public subnet (using lambda).

Comment: i am thinking if my python script is not tuned well... Let me try to to connect  and initiate from my lambda, aurora (scenario 2) and transfer data to my EC2 instance (scenario 1) and see how it works..... It might be a dumb idea, but worth a try...